# How to look through a sheet and find a value, get the column, and then count how many times a value appears in that column

Tags: excel

I am working with data that is sent to me.  The sheets always contain the same headers though they aren't really headers because it doesn't come in table form, but the columns change every pull so it is never in the same column so I can't do the Index Match like I'm used to. I need to get this to work without converting the data to a table because others that use this don't know how to do that. Is there a way to search the sheet to find the cell containing the value, capture that column address, and then count how many times the column contains a letter?

I have a front excel page that keeps account of how many times something happens.  Currently I use this formula =COUNTIF('UDO '!AJ:AJ,"Y").  It works the only thing is that I can't set it up as an array because the column isn't always AJ, so I'm always having to change it manually and I'd like to automate it.  So I want to be able to search the sheet that contains the information for the text value example: "Review Required FY*" and get the column that contains this (it should be a unique value) then I want to look down that column and countif it has a "Y" or "y" marked in the cell.  The sheets are always varying in length and column numbers.  I thought about using an HLookUp but I can't get it to work. I also could not get Index Match to work, because I never know how much data or the column order the Audit tab will be in or have.

So on the Main tab I have a cell that counts how many files I have to audit I want to go to Audit tab, look for "Review Required FY*", capture that column and count how many times "Y" or "y" are there.  I'd like to be able to set this up to do it all by itself.

I currently do not have any code because I can't find anything that works.

Comment: perhaps you could use a vlookup function or hlookup functions to find those header values you need: https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/look-up-a-single-value-with-vlookup-and-hlookup-in-excel/

Comment: Are the column headers always on the same row?

Comment: No the rows vary as well.  It's what makes it so difficult. I've used VLOOKUP for stuff, HLOOKUP, and Index Match for several other reports where I get stable data but with this one it either would take a lot of time to organize the mixture into an arrangement fitting those things, or I found it easier to just go find that column and then update that countif column formula.  It works but if I could find a way to do that by itself it would make the product more stable because I could lock the other peeps from making changes and just let it do it's thing.

Comment: It's the fact that the columns "ALWAYS" vary, and the Rows do to that makes it hard.  Nothing is ever in the same place twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the header only appears once, you can find out what row your header is in you can use an array formula like this (apply using Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=MAX(ROW(A1:A10)*COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1:Z1,ROW(A1:A10)-1,0),"Review Required FY*"))
```

(looks in the first 10 rows across A:Z)

You can feed the result of that into a lookup to find the column number.

EDIT - something like this:

[image]

The first formula needs to be entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter but the other 2 do not.

The 1000 in the last formula is a best guess at how much data there might be below your header - no problem setting that much larger to be on the safe side, as long as you don't try to count past the end of the sheet.

Comment: I've been trying to get it to work in the lookup but I'm having troubles with getting it to give me the column.  This did work to find the rows though on this months sheets it found that it was in row 5, and the two prior months it did find it in rows 12 and 7 respectively.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you so much.  With your example I was able to see where I was messing up and why I couldn't get the column reading to work.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

*Using VBA*

```
Option Explicit

Sub Looper()

Dim ws As Worksheet, Found As Range, LR As Long

For Each ws In Worksheets
    Set Found = ws.Cells.Find("Review Required FY*")
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, Found.Column), ws.Cells(LR, Found.Column)), "Y")
        End If
    Set Found = Nothing
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: The admin doesn't allow us to us VBA unfortunately, but thank you for this.